# bash: /bin/[application]_bundle: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano

I'm attempting to use Capistrano v3 w/ my Rails 4 application. When running `cap production bundle:install` I get:

```
DEBUG [019db9e4] Running if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/current'" 1>&2; false; fi on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [019db9e4] Command: if test ! -d /var/www/skateboxes/current; then echo "Directory does not exist '/var/www/skateboxes/current'" 1>&2; false; fi
DEBUG [019db9e4] Finished in 1.287 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 INFO [afc3725d] Running /bin/skateboxes_bundle --gemfile /var/www/skateboxes/current/Gemfile --path /var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /var/www/skateboxes/shared/bin --without development test on 162.243.33.179
DEBUG [afc3725d] Command: cd /var/www/skateboxes/current && ( RAILS_ENV=production /bin/skateboxes_bundle --gemfile /var/www/skateboxes/current/Gemfile --path /var/www/skateboxes/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --binstubs /var/www/skateboxes/shared/bin --without development test )
DEBUG [afc3725d]    bash: /bin/skateboxes_bundle: No such file or directory
cap aborted!
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:94:in `exit_status='
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:125:in `block (4 levels) in _execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `call'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:551:in `do_request'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:561:in `channel_request'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:147:in `block (2 levels) in _execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `call'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:514:in `do_open_confirmation'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:545:in `channel_open_confirmation'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:465:in `dispatch_incoming_packets'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:221:in `preprocess'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:205:in `process'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `block in loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/net-ssh-2.7.0/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:169:in `loop'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:149:in `block in _execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `tap'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:106:in `_execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:54:in `execute'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:20:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:81:in `within'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.0.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `instance_exec'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:42:in `run'
/Users/kyledecot/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@skateboxes/gems/sshkit-1.1.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
```